# What does !< mean?

Tags: handlebars.js, ghost-blog

I've been playing around with a theme for a ghost blog ([ghost.org](http://ghost.org)). It uses handlebars for its templates and  I've been looking at existing ones to see what is possible and what isn't.

I have come across `{{!< default}}`. `default` is the name of a template.

What does `!<` mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the `index.hbs` file of the default theme you'll find this comment:

```
{{! The comment above "< default" means - insert everything in this file into 
the {body} of the default.hbs template, which contains our header/footer. }}
```

It simply tells the page which parent template it should be inserted into

Comment: Ah I see. I never even looked at the default theme, I downloaded a 'blank' one to use as a skeleton and build on top of.

Answer (score 1):

According to [official page](http://handlebarsjs.com/) section about comments, `{{! }}` is used to mark a template comment. So, basically `< default` - just a comment which is simply being ignored.

EDIT:
Also in [mustache man page](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) it's clearly stated:

> Comments begin with a bang and are ignored.

So, I presume, it's safe to say, that if tag starts with `!`, it's not going to be rendered.